# При авторизации type basic в пароле неверно передается на сервер символ # swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Вот код формирования заголовка Basic:

```
let userName = "userName"
let userPassword = "{"pass":password}"
loginString = String(format: "%@:%@", userName, userPassword)
let loginData = loginString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
let base64LoginData = loginData.base64EncodedString()
let url = URL(string: "https://mysight.ru/authorize")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginData)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            self.data = data
            self.response = response as? HTTPURLResponse
            self.error = error

            if (response as? HTTPURLResponse) != nil {
                let myHttpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
                let statusCode = myHttpResponse.statusCode
                switch (statusCode) {
                    case 200:
                        print("Get UserTokens Processing StatusCode=200")
                    case 401:
                        print("User Unauthorized")
                    case 500:
                        print("Get UserTokens Processing StatusCode=500")

                    default:
                        print("Get UserTokens Processing StatusCode=Unknown")
                }
            }
            self.isFinished = true
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Если пароль содержит только буквы и цифры - все нормально, статус 200, если в пароле символ # - сразу ошибка: статус 401: пользователь неавторизован

Понимаю что проблема в передаче символа #, но как устранить данную проблему никак не пойму.
Если кто-то сталкивался, помогите плз.

Comment: Возможно дело не в свифте, а в сервере, авторизация иным способом работает? Например прямо на сайте или через `curl`

Comment: На сервере происходит просто сравнивание присланной от меня строки в base64 для пары логин/пароль с хранящейся строкой также в base64 для данного пользователя, которая создалась, когда он устанавливал себе пароль через регистрацию пользователя на сервере. Почему моя строка при наличии символа # в пароле отличается от серверной, вот в чем вопрос. Как это исправить?

Comment: Возможно, # воспринимается как спецсимвол. Можно попробовать заэкранировать #, т.е. найти в строке # и поставить впереди слэш: \#

Comment: ну вот простейший пример, дает верный результат `let data = "test#test#".data(using: .utf8)
let base64Str = data?.base64EncodedString()
print(base64Str)
// output dGVzdCN0ZXN0Iw==`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ оказался банальным: 
в строке let userPassword = "{"pass":password}"
были пропущены кавычки let userPassword = "{"pass":"password"}"

Поэтому строка JSON конвертировалась в String при наличие спецсимволов некорректно, после исправления все сразу заработало :)))